# two rmd knit successfully but when combine context into one, error occurs

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

When I knit two rmd files seperately, they both output html well. But when I combine the context together, the error message occurs.

pandoc document conversion failed with error 1033
´ËÍâ: There were 18 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

Comment: That's funny, when I combine two rmd files together, it works very well. Could it be that your files are different than mine? :-) Why don't you create a minimal example – two really, really small files that you can post here but which fail when combined. Second, why don't you do what R tells you to do and use `warnings()` to see them? Usually they are helpful. You should also post them here. In general, read the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) article.

Answer (score 1):

The RStudio IDE comes bundled with the preferred version of pandoc that works with the latest version of knitr (https://yihui.name/en/2018/06/time-for-pandoc-2-x/). So, rather than manually update pandoc, as others have suggested, you could also update your version of RStudio.

I just ran into a similar error and updating my version of RStudio resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you, but I had the same error with just a single Rmd file (although there were no warnings). I solved it by manually installing the latest version of pandoc. (Just replaced the pandoc exe files in the RStudio installation folder with the new ones from pandoc's download page.)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was just installing the latest version from here: https://pandoc.org/installing.html